# Ionic - Can't get value of ion-input when there is *ngIf in tag <form>

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building an hybrid app using Ionic 3 and Angular, and I'm stuck on this:

I have a form and I only want it to appear depending on a condition in controller.

**Controller:**

```
export class ClassName implements OnInit{
  private show: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit(){
    if(someCondition){
      this.show = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**View:**

```
<ion-content>
<button ion-button small block full color="danger" (click)="sum(discount.value)">Cancelar</button>

    <form *ngIf="show">  
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label  floating>Discount ($)</ion-label>
            <ion-input  #discount type="number"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </form>
```

**The problem is** that when the variable show's value is true (the form is visible/showing) and when I click the button, nothing happens, no errors either. But when I remove the *ngIf="show" from tag , then the click button calls the function correctly.

I don't know what the problem is and I don't want just to hide the form using something like [hidden], I don't want it to be created if the condition is false.

Could it be some kind of binding problem?

I already tried to put the condition in the ionViewWIllEnter(), but nothing changes..

I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have a lot of approachs to do this task.

First you must need to know that in angular you have two types of directives, the structural ones and the no structural.

The structural directives are the directives that will remove or add a block of html from the view, for example: `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, `*ngSwitch`.

The other type of directive is like in this case the `floating` directive in your `ion-label` it will modify the element but it will not remove it from the template, maybe hide or display it with css properties.

That said, you can use a `NgModel` to bind the vlue of your discount input and when the input is not there anymore you still have the value.

**Component**

```
export class ClassName implements OnInit{
  private show: boolean = false;
  public discount: number = 0;

  ngOnInit(){
    if(someCondition){
      this.show = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<button ion-button small block full color="danger" (click)="sum(discount)">Cancelar</button>

<form *ngIf="!show">  
   <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
         <ion-label  floating>Discount ($)</ion-label>
         <ion-input  type="number" [(ngModel)]="discount"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
</form>
```

That will do the job, remember that if you have a `[hidden]` directive, is less performant than a `*ngIf` because angular will still check the status and the conditions of the block of html hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The `*ngIf` does not simply show or hide the component, it actually creates or removes the instance of the component from the template.

To show or hide your component you could use the `hidden` attribute like this :

```
<form [hidden]="!show">  
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
         <ion-label  floating>Discount ($)</ion-label>
         <ion-input  #discount type="number"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```